# Install specific version of gcc using yum

Tags: linux, gcc, yum

How do I ask `yum` to install specific version of `gcc`? When I run `yum install gcc` on 
fc17 I get gcc 4.7.2. My software compiles just fine using this version of gcc. Recently I was forced to move to fc18, when I run `yum install gcc` I get gcc 4.8, and my software fails to compile with this version of gcc. Since so I'm forced to manually download the gcc-4.7.2.fc18.rpm and to resolve dependencies manually. Is there a way to ask `yum` to install a specific version of gcc?

Comment: You should be scared if your software compiles with GCC 4.7 but not 4.8. It is probably a symptom of a significant issue.

Comment: Actually I didn't get a compilation error, but I got a huge amount of compilation warnings from 3rd party code like boost. After I used gcc diagnostic around the includes statements of boost code I was able to compile my code successfully without warnings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the version of the package to install along with the name, e.g. "gcc-4.7.2". But that won't help since 4.7.2 is not in the F18 repositories; [fix your code](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html).

Comment: It's true gcc-4.7.2 is not in fc18 default yum repository, however, the rpm exists in other repositories. Adding one of those repositories certainly answers my question.